# How to reload a page after downloading an excel file?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a link in a web page, when I download excel file, page isn't reloading.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve it?

**Controller**

`public function submission_list(Request $request)
    {
            })->download('xlsx');
        return redirect('/batch-to-mbsb-process-2')->with('message', 'Submission list created successfully'); 
}`

**Blade**

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">                         
     <button id="download-link" class="download btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i> Create Submission List</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you using ajax call to download the excel sheet?

Comment: If yes you could use `window.location.href = window.location.href` on your ajax success

Comment: not,, just link direct to controller laravel,,,

Comment: @ialx You need to give more of your code so that we can see what you are doing

Comment: @Josh please check below

Answer (score 0):

```html
 @extends('vadmin.tampilan')


@section('content')
 <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row clearfix"> <!-- Breadcrumber -->

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-col-pink">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">donut_small</i> Ready to MBSB</a></li>

                    </ol>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- End of breadcrumber -->

            @include('shared.notif')

            <div id="message" style="display: none">
       <div id="message-screen-mask" class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>
       <div id="message-text" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable waitmessage">please wait...</div>
   </div>


   <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="header bg-red">
                  <h2>Ready to MBSB</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">

                  <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="popup-validation" action="{{ url('/submission_list')}}" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                      <table class="table table-hover dashboard-task-infos" id="example">
                      
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>#</th>
                                  <th>Name</th>
                                  <th>IC</th>
                                  <th>Phone</th>
                                  <th>Status</th> 
                                  <th width="5%">Action</th>
                                  <!-- <th>Batch Header</th> -->
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                              <?php $i = 1; ?>

                              @foreach($mbsb as $data)
                              <tr>
                                  <td>{{$i++}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$data->ic}}</td>
                                  <td>{{$data->notelp}}</td>
                                  <!-- <td>
                                       <button class="btn btn-success" aria-controls="collapse-{{$data->id}}" data-target="#collapseDetailOne{{$data->id}}" data-toggle="collapse" style="cursor:pointer;">Detail</button>
                                  </td>-->
                                  <td>
                                       <span class="label bg-deep-orange">Ready to MBSB</span>
                                  </td> 
                                  <!-- <td>
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect m-r-20" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal{{$data->id}}">Detail</button>
                                  </td> -->
                                  <td>
                                   <div class="demo-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" id="basic_checkbox_{{$i}}" name="id[]" value="{{$data->id}}" />
                                                <label for="basic_checkbox_{{$i}}"></label>
                                                
                                                
                                                <input type="hidden"  name="cus_id[]" value="{{$data->id_cus}}">

                                                <input type="hidden"  name="ids[]" value="">
                                                <input type="hidden"  name="sta[]" value="">
                                            </div>

                                  </td>
                                  <!-- <td>
                                   @if($data->doc == 1)
                                            <a href="{{url('/pdfbatchheader/'.$data->id_cus)}}" class="btn bg-pink btn-circle waves-effect" target="_blank"> <i class="material-icons">dns</i> </a>
                                            @else
                                            -
                                            @endif
                                  </td> -->
                              </tr>

                              @endforeach
                              
                          </tbody>
        
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">                      
                            <button id="download-link" class="download btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i> Create Submission List</button>
                           </div>
                         </form>
                      </table>

                  
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
   </div>

   
   @foreach($mbsb as $datas)
            <!-- Large Size -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="largeModal{{$datas->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header bg-red">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="largeModalLabel">Detail</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <p><b>Note :</b></p>
                            <textarea id="txtArea" name="notep6" class="form-control" rows="6" cols="5" readonly></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach


   <!-- ///////////////////  Data Target  //////////////// -->
      @foreach($mbsb as $datas)
      <div id="collapseDetailOne{{$datas->id}}" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-collapse-group="collapse-group" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="row clearfix">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="header bg-red">
                      <h2>Detail {{$datas->name}}</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="body">
                     
                       

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      @endforeach
      <!-- ///////////////////  End Data Target  //////////////// -->

  </div>
 </section>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example').DataTable();
         });
 </script>

 <!-- Checkbox detect -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( '#popup-validation' ).on('submit', function(e) {
           if($( 'input[class^="invitation-friends"]:checked' ).length === 0) {
              alert( 'Please! Select the application' );
              e.preventDefault();
           }
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     $("#download-link").click(function(){
      progressbar.hide();
   });
    </script>
 
@endsection
```

```
public function submission_list(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $username = Auth::user();

    $item = array_map(null, $request->id, $request->cus_id,  $request->ids, $request->sta);


        $hariini  = date('ymd');


        $bc = Batch::latest('created_at')->limit('1')->first();

        if(empty($bc->uniq_id)){
            $l = 'B000-181003';                
        }
        else{
            $l = $bc->uniq_id;
        }

        $letter = substr($l,0,1);
        $nu = substr($l,1,3);

        if($nu == 999){
            $letter++;
            $nu=1;
        }
        else{
            $nu++;
        }

        $cc=  $letter.str_pad($nu,3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).$hariini;
        $pra = praapplication::select('uniq_no')->get();

        $today  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $format = date('Ymd-Hi');
        $number = 'B'.$format;

        $validate = Batch::latest('created_at')->where('uniq_id',$cc)->count();

        if($validate==0){
            $batch          = new Batch;
            $batch->uniq_id = $cc;
            $batch->date    = $today;
            $batch->save();

        foreach($item as $val) {

            $pra = praapplication::Where('id',$val[0])->update([

                "uniq_no"   =>$cc,
                "submission"   =>'1',
                "stage"  => 'W17'

            ]);

            $pra = Report::where('cus_id',$val[1])->update([

                "submission"   =>'1',
                "date_submission"  => $today

            ]);

            }
        }


        //Dia Download
    $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $excel = Excel::create('Submission'.$current, function($excel) use($cc, $item, $username, $current) {

        $excel->setTitle('Global Submission');

        // Chain the setters
        $excel->setCreator('Global')->setCompany('Global');

        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($cc, $item, $username, $current) {

        $submission = praapplication::join('emp', 'emp.id', '=', 'praapplication.emp_code')
            ->select(
              'praapplication.updated_at', 
              'praapplication.name', 
              'praapplication.ic',
              'praapplication.email',
              'emp.Emp_Desc')
            ->orderBy('praapplication.created_at', 'desc')->where('praapplication.stage', '=', 'W17')->where('uniq_no',$cc)
            ->get();

            $i = 1;
                foreach($submission as $product) {
                 $data[] = array(
                    $i++,
                    $product->updated_at->toFormattedDateString(),
                    $product->name,
                    $product->ic,
                    $product->email,
                    $product->Emp_Desc,
                );
            }

            $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);
                $ir = $i-1;
                $is = $i+1;
              $range = "A1:F{$ir}";
            $sheet->setBorder($range, 'thin');
            $headings = array('No', 'Date','Customers Name','New IC', 'Email', 'Company');
             $sheet->setBorder( "A{$is}:F{$is}" ,'none');
            //$sheet->setBorder('A2:A10');
            $sheet->prependRow(1, $headings);
            // add header
            $current = date('Y-m-d ');
                $sheet->prependRow(1, ["MASTER AGENT : GLOBAL I EXCEED MANAGEMENT SDN BHD"]);
                $sheet->mergeCells("A1:F1");

                $sheet->prependRow(2, ["Batch Header : ".$cc]);
                $sheet->mergeCells("A2:F2");

                $sheet->prependRow(3, [""]);
                $sheet->mergeCells("A3:F3");


                $sheet->cell("A1:A3", function($cell) {
                    // change header color

                    $cell->setBackground('#ffffff')
                        ->setFontColor('#000000')
                        ->setFontWeight('bold')
                        ->setAlignment('center')
                        ->setValignment('center');
                      // ->setBorder('none', 'none', 'thin', 'thin');
                });


                $footerRow = count($submission) + 3;
                $sheet->appendRow([ "Name : ".$username->name ]);
                $sheet->appendRow([ "Date : ".$current ]);

                $sheet->mergeCells("A{$footerRow}:B{$footerRow}");

                $sheet->cell("A{$footerRow}:B{$footerRow}", function($cell) {
                    $cell->setAlignment('center')
                        ->setValignment('center')
                        ->setFontColor('#000000')
                        ->setFontSize(10);
                });
            });

        })->download('xlsx');


    //return Redirect::to('/batch-to-mbsb-process-2')->with('message', 'Submission list created successfully');

    return redirect('/batch-to-mbsb-process-2')->with('message', 'Submission list created successfully');
}
```